# Ignore "prevent sleep" request from a specific app

Tags: macbook-pro, power-management, spotify

I sometimes have the problem that my macbook won't sleep, even with the lid closed.
After some investigation I tracked the problem down to Spotify app; when the app is open, even if no song is playing, my macbook won't go to sleep and eventually go out of battery power.
I don't have need of spotify keeping my mac awake (for obvious reason I'm ok with a video player or a game instead); is there a way to ignore its request for preventing sleep without affecting other applications?
I know I could quit spotify when not using it, but I am prone to forget it and it's very annoying to find my mac completely drained...

EDIT: to be clearer, I am not looking for a solution about Spotify specifically (I could simply uninstall it and forget about it), I am just looking for an option which is the default in both Linux and Windows, that is that the user always overrides any setting when he/she closes the lid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your MacBook should always sleep when the lid is closed.** If your Mac is not sleeping with the lid closed, this suggests a problem.

There are exceptions:

- Some MacBooks can be plugged into external displays and, once connected, the MacBook's lid can be safely closed without triggering system wide sleep.
- Previously it has been possible to install a third party kernel extension to override macOS's behaviour and [stop sleep with the lid closed](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2389/). Doing this carries risk and should be avoided.

#### Blocking Sleep

It is difficult for user space processes to block sleep. Sleep assertions should never block a user initiated sleep, either via closing the lid or requesting sleep from the Finder. Use [`pmset`](https://www.dssw.co.uk/reference/pmset.html) to view current power assertions:

```
pmset -g assertions
```

Comment: I know the problem with external displays and it's not my case; also I didn't install anything which tampered with energy management (I know tools like Caffeine, but I simply don't need them on my macbook).
When the lid is closed the computer is usually off, but I have experienced once or twice when this was not the case: the "prevent sleep" settings acted above it

Comment: The behaviour you are seeing suggests a lower level bug in macOS, a problem with connected hardware, or a bug in the hardware of the Mac. This assumes there are no third party kernel extensions installed.

Comment: I think I will go the easy way and throw spotify away :-)
I will also try to understand if something is wrong with my macbook

Answer (score 2):

To manually initiate a sleep on the mac and override 'Preventing Sleep' applications run

`pmset sleepnow`

in the terminal

**Edit**

**I agree, the Apple spec is flawed, Apple need to fix this!!!**, there should definitely be a way to override the 'prevent sleep' system wide, however the above is the best *workaround* I've found...

...and if you want something that does a bit more checking (some apps I've discovered still prevent sleeping with the above command)

```
function slp2 {
  #add a list of programs here that you will always wish to close
  pkill -x qemu-system-i386
  pkill -x qemu-system-x86_64
  sleep 2
  assertion=$(pmset -g assertions | egrep 'PreventUserIdleSystemSleep');
  canSleep=${assertion:34:1};
  if [ $canSleep != "0" ]; then
    say "cannot sleep, please close offending applications"
  else
    pmset displaysleepnow
    say "goodnight, rest well"
  fi
}
```

You can also assign this to a Keyboard Maestro command so you don't need to open up a terminal and type in.  Keyboard Maestro has an 'At system sleep' trigger (possibly there is some other commands, lid close maybe!) that may help further.

**Edit2**
Updated my Mac to Sonoma (14) and my mac again stays on all night or drains the battery! (come on Apple, save some carbon emissions!)
I think it is because I have bluetooth set to on.
So, I installed sleepwatcher (run commands when we sleep / wake the computer) & blueutil (allows us to switch on and off bluetooth)

```
brew install sleepwatcher
brew services start sleepwatcher
brew install blueutil
```

Now, create a .wakeup file and a .sleep file in your `/Users/yourusername` directory.

.sleep

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/local/bin/blueutil --power 0
```

.wakeup

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/local/bin/blueutil --power 1
```

Comment: Thank you, this works! Now I can force my Mac to go sleep by pressing a custom keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes have this issue with Spotify.
An application can block sleeping even when laptop's lid is closed, ie by calling:

```
[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] beginActivityWithOptions:NSActivityUserInitiated reason:@"Good Reason"];
```

I suppose we shoudn't do that to prevent AppNap but the documentation is not very clear.